# EntityFramework Optional 1 to 1 or 0 Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having trouble getting this set up correctly.  Given the following classes:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long ToDoId { get; set; }

    public long? ResultId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResultId")]
    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Result
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Looking at some examples it appears that the following line configuring the Item class should work:

```
HasOptional(x => x.Result).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But this just gets a validation error:

```
Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

How should this be configures.  Some examples are configuring the Item class and some are configuring the Result class and I'm getting a little confused about which way around this should be configured in order to work.

What I'm looking for is when an Item is deleted the corresponding Result is also deleted.

Comment: If you want to have 1 to 1 or 0 relation. Property ResultId should be a primary key in both tables. Other way it will be 1 to *

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework doesn't support unique constraints (unique foreign keys). You must use a shared primary key to get this relationship.

Try this:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long ToDoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Or in Fluent:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Result)
    .WithRequired(f => f.Item)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```